# Extension to hide Safari toolbar

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

I used to have an extension that hided the toolbar completely (which I installed from a website, outside the extensions market) giving a minimalist look, but it suddenly got removed from my Safari for some reason, and I can't find it back in Google.

Luckily I had a screenshot of the extension running:

[image]

Does anyone knows how was this extension called, and probably why it got removed without any notice?

Comment: You know you can just select *View* -> *Hide Toolbar* in Safari... no extension required.

Comment: @sdmeyers Works nice! I remember installing an extension for this in the past though, weird. Do you mind answering the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just select View -> Hide Toolbar in Safari... no extension required